# php session login not loading in http but only in https

Tags: php, sql, http, https, cpanel

In **HTTPS**(*https://brian.com*), whenever I try to login using a login form, the session starts and everything runs okay. 
But when i try to use **HTTP**(*http://brian.com*), the login session does not start. The form just clears and nothing happens even error reporting.
Registration form works fine on both.
What can be the reason and the solution behind it.

(*brian.com* is just an example in this question)

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some cookies with same name for an '.myhost.com' and for a 'myhost.com' (w/o a dot)?
When you send session ID from a cookie, then sessionId has been reloaded twice:

`PHPSESSID:.myhost.com`

and

`PHPSESSID:myhost.com`

... I'm very tired to fight ... (((